# Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, object given

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am using `Laravel 5.5`  and I have translated the following query:

```
        'SELECT *
        FROM instruments
        LEFT join financials on instruments.id=financials.instruments_id
        WHERE financials.id IN
        ( SELECT MAX(financials.id)
        FROM financials
        GROUP BY financials.instruments_id )
        ORDER BY instruments.id ASC'
```

into eloquent:

```
    $overviewArray = DB::table('instruments')
        ->leftJoin('financials', 'instruments.id', '=', 'financials.instruments_id')
        ->whereIn('financials.id', DB::raw('SELECT MAX(financials.id)
        FROM financials
        GROUP BY financials.instruments_id )
        ORDER BY instruments.id ASC'))->get()->toArray();
```

However, I get the following error:

In Grammar.php line 135:

```
  Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, object given, called
  in C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Coding Projects\laravel_project\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Gramm
  ars\Grammar.php on line 250
```

My guess is that my eloquent query is wrong? Any suggestions what is wrong with it?

I appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 $overviewArray = DB::table('instruments')
    ->leftJoin('financials', 'instruments.id', '=', inancials.instruments_id')
    ->whereIn('financials.id', function($query){
      $query->select(DB::raw('MAX(financials.id)'))->
     from('financials')->
     groupBy('financials.instruments_id');})
    ->orderBy('instruments.id')
    ->get()
    ->toArray();
```

I guess it will be ok.

Comment: Thx for your answer! However, it does not resolve my issue. I still get the same error.

Comment: @mrquad Try again, I changed a little.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was because I was doing `Event::get(44)` instead of `Event::find(44)`.